# How do I nest these classes and FlexBox function?

Tags: c++, class, flexbox, nested, juce

I am working within JUCE to try to create a flexible panel structure for audio synthesizer use. In general the goal is to create something that looks sort of like this:

[image: Panel Look]

Where there are labeled groups of labeled knobs.

I am using JUCE and C++, which has a FlexBox function that allows auto-organization of elements on the screen which is ideal. I have this outcome at present:
[image: FlexBox Simple Panel Working]

Where all those labeled knobs are flexibly laid out on the screen.

The way it works is each knob is a "slider" which is a built in JUCE class, and it is labeled by the GroupComponent class named "LabeledSlider". An ownedarray then picks up all objects of LabeledSlider, and the built in FlexBox function autoarranges this array on the screen.

This is that working code, which includes just a simple sinewave generator based on frequency & amplitude knobs:

```
class LabeledSlider : public GroupComponent

{
    public:
    LabeledSlider (const String& name)
    {
        setText (name);
        setTextLabelPosition (Justification::centredTop);
        addAndMakeVisible (slider);
    }

    void resized() override
    {
        slider.setBounds (getLocalBounds().reduced (10));
    }

    Slider slider 
    { 
        Slider::RotaryHorizontalVerticalDrag, Slider::TextBoxBelow 
    };


};



class MainContentComponent : public AudioAppComponent
{
public:
    MainContentComponent()

    {

        LabeledSlider* control = new LabeledSlider("Frequency");
        control->slider.setRange(20.0, 20000.0);
        control->slider.setSkewFactorFromMidPoint(500.0);
        control->slider.setNumDecimalPlacesToDisplay(1);
        control->slider.setValue(currentFrequency, dontSendNotification);
        control->slider.onValueChange = [this] { targetFrequency = frequency.slider.getValue(); };
        control->slider.setTextBoxStyle(Slider::TextBoxBelow, false, 100, 20);
        control->slider.setRange(50.0, 5000.0);
        control->slider.setSkewFactorFromMidPoint(500.0);
        control->slider.setNumDecimalPlacesToDisplay(1);
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Level");
        control->slider.setRange(0.0, 1.0);
        control->slider.onValueChange = [this] { targetLevel = (float)level.slider.getValue(); };
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy1");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy2");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy3");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy4");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy5");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy6");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy7");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy8");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy9");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));


    setSize (600, 600);
    setAudioChannels (0, 2); // no inputs, two outputs
    }

    ~MainContentComponent()
    {
        shutdownAudio();
    }

    void resized() override
    {

        //==============================================================================
        FlexBox knobBox;
        knobBox.flexWrap = FlexBox::Wrap::wrap;
        knobBox.justifyContent = FlexBox::JustifyContent::flexStart;
        knobBox.alignContent = FlexBox::AlignContent::flexStart;


        for (auto* k : knobs)
            knobBox.items.add(FlexItem(*k).withMinHeight(80.0f).withMinWidth(80.0f).withFlex(1));

        //==============================================================================
        FlexBox fb;
        fb.flexDirection = FlexBox::Direction::column;
        fb.items.add(FlexItem(knobBox).withFlex(2.5));
        fb.performLayout(getLocalBounds().toFloat());


    }

    inline void updateAngleDelta()
    {
        auto cyclesPerSample = currentFrequency / currentSampleRate;
        angleDelta = cyclesPerSample * 2.0 * MathConstants<double>::pi;
    }

    void prepareToPlay (int, double sampleRate) override
    {
        currentSampleRate = sampleRate;
        updateAngleDelta();
    }

    void releaseResources() override {}

    void getNextAudioBlock (const AudioSourceChannelInfo& bufferToFill) override
    {
        auto* leftBuffer  = bufferToFill.buffer->getWritePointer (0, bufferToFill.startSample);
        auto* rightBuffer = bufferToFill.buffer->getWritePointer (1, bufferToFill.startSample);

        auto localTargetFrequency = targetFrequency;

        if (targetFrequency != currentFrequency)
        {
            auto frequencyIncrement = (targetFrequency - currentFrequency) / bufferToFill.numSamples;

            for (auto sample = 0; sample < bufferToFill.numSamples; ++sample)
            {
                auto currentSample = (float) std::sin (currentAngle);
                currentFrequency += frequencyIncrement;
                updateAngleDelta();
                currentAngle += angleDelta;
                leftBuffer[sample]  = currentSample;
                rightBuffer[sample] = currentSample;
            }

            currentFrequency = localTargetFrequency;
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto sample = 0; sample < bufferToFill.numSamples; ++sample)
            {
                auto currentSample = (float) std::sin (currentAngle);
                currentAngle += angleDelta;
                leftBuffer[sample]  = currentSample;
                rightBuffer[sample] = currentSample;
            }
        }

        auto localTargetLevel = targetLevel;
        bufferToFill.buffer->applyGainRamp (bufferToFill.startSample, bufferToFill.numSamples, currentLevel, localTargetLevel);
        currentLevel = localTargetLevel;
    }

private:
    double currentSampleRate = 0.0, currentAngle = 0.0, angleDelta = 0.0;
    double currentFrequency = 500.0, targetFrequency = 500.0;
    float currentLevel = 0.1f, targetLevel = 0.1f;
    int rotaryDiam = 100;

    LabeledSlider frequency{ "Frequency" };
    LabeledSlider level{ "Level" };
    LabeledSlider dummy1{ "Dummy 1" };
    LabeledSlider dummy2{ "Dummy 2" };
    LabeledSlider dummy3{ "Dummy 3" };
    LabeledSlider dummy4{ "Dummy 4" };
    LabeledSlider dummy5{ "Dummy 5" };
    LabeledSlider dummy6{ "Dummy 6" };
    LabeledSlider dummy7{ "Dummy 7" };
    LabeledSlider dummy8{ "Dummy 8" };
    LabeledSlider dummy9{ "Dummy 9" };

    OwnedArray<LabeledSlider> knobs;

    JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (MainContentComponent)
};
```

I would like to now add a second layer of FlexBox by grouping knobs into a bigger class called "LabeledGroup", so that every 'LabeledSlider' when defined should belong to a LabeledGroup.

Then the same FlexBox function can be used to automatically organize the knobs within the LabeledGroups and also organize the LabeledGroups themselves.

I am new to all this though so although I've spent hours now reading about nested classes, I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is my crude attempt at reorganizing the above code though it obviously doesn't work:

```
class LabeledGroup : public GroupComponent

{

public:

    LabeledGroup(const String& name)
    {
        setText(name);
        setTextLabelPosition(Justification::centredTop);


        class LabeledSlider : public GroupComponent
        {
        public:
            LabeledSlider(const String& name)
            {
                setText(name);
                setTextLabelPosition(Justification::centredTop);
                addAndMakeVisible(slider);
            }

            void resized() override
            {
                slider.setBounds(getLocalBounds().reduced(10));
            }

            Slider slider
            {
                Slider::RotaryHorizontalVerticalDrag, Slider::TextBoxBelow
            };

        };

    }

private:
    void resized() override
    {

        OwnedArray<LabeledSlider> knobs;

        //==============================================================================
        FlexBox knobBox;
        knobBox.flexWrap = FlexBox::Wrap::wrap;
        knobBox.justifyContent = FlexBox::JustifyContent::flexStart;
        knobBox.alignContent = FlexBox::AlignContent::flexStart;

        for (auto* k : knobs)
            knobBox.items.add(FlexItem(*k).withMinHeight(80.0f).withMinWidth(80.0f).withFlex(1));

        //==============================================================================
        FlexBox fb;
        fb.flexDirection = FlexBox::Direction::column;
        fb.items.add(FlexItem(knobBox).withFlex(2.5));
        fb.performLayout(getLocalBounds().toFloat());

    }

};




class MainContentComponent : public AudioAppComponent
{
public:
    MainContentComponent()

    {
        addAndMakeVisible(group1);

        LabeledSlider* control = new LabeledSlider("Frequency");
        control->slider.setRange(20.0, 20000.0);
        control->slider.setSkewFactorFromMidPoint(500.0);
        control->slider.setNumDecimalPlacesToDisplay(1);
        control->slider.setValue(currentFrequency, dontSendNotification);
        control->slider.onValueChange = [this] { targetFrequency = frequency.slider.getValue(); };
        control->slider.setTextBoxStyle(Slider::TextBoxBelow, false, 100, 20);
        control->slider.setRange(50.0, 5000.0);
        control->slider.setSkewFactorFromMidPoint(500.0);
        control->slider.setNumDecimalPlacesToDisplay(1);
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Level");
        control->slider.setRange(0.0, 1.0);
        control->slider.onValueChange = [this] { targetLevel = (float)level.slider.getValue(); };
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy1");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy2");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy3");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy4");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy5");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy6");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy7");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy8");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy9");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));

    setSize (600, 600);
    setAudioChannels (0, 2); // no inputs, two outputs
    }

    ~MainContentComponent()
    {
        shutdownAudio();
    }

    void resized() override
    {

        //==============================================================================
        FlexBox knobBox;
        knobBox.flexWrap = FlexBox::Wrap::wrap;
        knobBox.justifyContent = FlexBox::JustifyContent::flexStart;
        knobBox.alignContent = FlexBox::AlignContent::flexStart;

        for (auto* k : knobgroup)
            knobBox.items.add(FlexItem(*k).withMinHeight(80.0f).withMinWidth(80.0f).withFlex(1));

        //==============================================================================
        FlexBox fb;
        fb.flexDirection = FlexBox::Direction::column;
        fb.items.add(FlexItem(knobBox).withFlex(2.5));
        fb.performLayout(getLocalBounds().toFloat());


    }

    inline void updateAngleDelta()
    {
        auto cyclesPerSample = currentFrequency / currentSampleRate;
        angleDelta = cyclesPerSample * 2.0 * MathConstants<double>::pi;
    }

    void prepareToPlay (int, double sampleRate) override
    {
        currentSampleRate = sampleRate;
        updateAngleDelta();
    }

    void releaseResources() override {}

    void getNextAudioBlock (const AudioSourceChannelInfo& bufferToFill) override
    {
        auto* leftBuffer  = bufferToFill.buffer->getWritePointer (0, bufferToFill.startSample);
        auto* rightBuffer = bufferToFill.buffer->getWritePointer (1, bufferToFill.startSample);

        auto localTargetFrequency = targetFrequency;

        if (targetFrequency != currentFrequency)
        {
            auto frequencyIncrement = (targetFrequency - currentFrequency) / bufferToFill.numSamples;

            for (auto sample = 0; sample < bufferToFill.numSamples; ++sample)
            {
                auto currentSample = (float) std::sin (currentAngle);
                currentFrequency += frequencyIncrement;
                updateAngleDelta();
                currentAngle += angleDelta;
                leftBuffer[sample]  = currentSample;
                rightBuffer[sample] = currentSample;
            }

            currentFrequency = localTargetFrequency;
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto sample = 0; sample < bufferToFill.numSamples; ++sample)
            {
                auto currentSample = (float) std::sin (currentAngle);
                currentAngle += angleDelta;
                leftBuffer[sample]  = currentSample;
                rightBuffer[sample] = currentSample;
            }
        }

        auto localTargetLevel = targetLevel;
        bufferToFill.buffer->applyGainRamp (bufferToFill.startSample, bufferToFill.numSamples, currentLevel, localTargetLevel);
        currentLevel = localTargetLevel;
    }

private:
    double currentSampleRate = 0.0, currentAngle = 0.0, angleDelta = 0.0;
    double currentFrequency = 500.0, targetFrequency = 500.0;
    float currentLevel = 0.1f, targetLevel = 0.1f;
    int rotaryDiam = 100;

    LabeledSlider frequency{ "Frequency" };
    LabeledSlider level{ "Level" };
    LabeledSlider dummy1{ "Dummy 1" };
    LabeledSlider dummy2{ "Dummy 2" };
    LabeledSlider dummy3{ "Dummy 3" };
    LabeledSlider dummy4{ "Dummy 4" };
    LabeledSlider dummy5{ "Dummy 5" };
    LabeledSlider dummy6{ "Dummy 6" };
    LabeledSlider dummy7{ "Dummy 7" };
    LabeledSlider dummy8{ "Dummy 8" };
    LabeledSlider dummy9{ "Dummy 9" };

    LabeledGroup group1{ "Group 1" };

    OwnedArray<LabeledGroup> knobgroup;
  JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (MainContentComponent)
```

I'm new to both C++ and JUCE so this is tricky for me.

My main problem at the present (if the principle is sound) is that I don't know how to get the "ownedarray" working inside the LabeledGroup class so that any LabeledSliders defined within a given LabeledGroup are automatically picked up by it and thus organized by the built-in FlexBox.

I also don't know how to define the knobs as LabeledSliders that belong to a given LabeledGroup. ie. How to re-write the slider declarations so a group is designated.

Thanks if you've read all this. Any help would be very appreciated. It's hard to figure out these sorts of things when you're new and you haven't seen real examples of the application before.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what benefit is there to nesting classes versus using external classes?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know if they actually need to be nested. What I need is: (1) A class for a LabeledGroup. This group must create an array containing all objects from LabeledSliders that are assigned to it. (2) FlexBox must then auto-arrange all the LabeledSliders in each LabeledGroup. (3) FlexBox must lastly be used to auto-arrange all the LabeledGroups. I don't know enough about C++ in general to know the "right" way to do this. I was thinking it was to nest Labeled Sliders into LabeledGroup but maybe it can all be done separately?

Comment: A widget can *contain* other widgets without using nested classes.  Remember that a class can be thought as a stencil for containing data.  Not to be confused with an *instance* of the class.  There is less complexity without using nested classes.

Comment: Okay Thomas, fair enough. I can see how that would be the case. Let's say I take the original first working code posted in my question, and I add to it a separate class "LabeledGroup". Then I make an object from it called "group1". Currently, the knobs are being generated by: 
"
        control = new LabeledSlider("Dummy4");
        addAndMakeVisible(knobs.add(control));" 

"
    LabeledSlider dummy4{ "Dummy 4" };" 

How do I rewrite those lines so that dummy4 LabeledSlider can be treated as part of "group1"? I hope that makes sense. I think that will work if I can do that.